# simple rating bar dependency error

Tags: android, rating

I'm trying to add this dependency: compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5' but is not working.

This is my build.gradle Module App:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cristiana.licentaapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the Project Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not resolve com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/iarcuschin/simpleratingbar/0.1.5/simpleratingbar-0.1.5.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/iarcuschin/simpleratingbar/0.1.5/simpleratingbar-0.1.5.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/5.153.35.248] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

I added same here successfully.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.summit.paytmdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    }
```

Comment: what you recommended me to change? your code is almost like mine

Comment: try to change sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your access to jcenter is limited. To solve this issue configure your proxy properly:

Go to : `File> Settings...> Appearance & Behavior> System Settings> HTTP Proxy` and configure it.

Make sure your SDK and Android Studio and gradle are updated